# How do i remove the changes(commits) from showiing up in the Jenkins Changes tab of some cloned repos while running the build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, cicd

I have a Jenkinsfile that clones three repositories while building; the code repo, the kubernetes configuration repo and a repo for various automation scripts.

When running the job I see the commits of the Kubernetes and scripts repo plus the code repo. I just want developers to see the commits made to the code repo.

[Picture of the commit history shown in workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lFKN.png)

In the above picture, a majority of the commits were from the scripts and kubernetes environment configs and I would like jenkins to not show those.

I have tried searching for this issue but I might not be wording it properly. I have also realised the way I do it might not be best practice but I'm the only one implementing this at my company and I'm mostly using documentation + chatgpt to implement functionality. So I haven't found a solution by googling it or on stack. Any help is deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.